# XSLT: UTC TimeStamp convert into Time Zone using adjust-dateTime-to-timezone

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt

I'm trying to covert a UTC timestamp based on some time zone information in the XML into my target TZ dependent timestamp.

Using the xslt funtion `adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($utc-timestamp, xs:dayTimeDuration('PT2H')` this is not a problem but the conversion must be dynamic based on the TZ information from the source file (mainly Java TZs).

Just an example which is working but not really dynamic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/InputDateTime">
        <xs:testDate>
            <xsl:variable name="targetTimeZone" select="TargetTimeZone/node()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="utc-timestamp" select="UTCDateTime"/>

            <xsl:variable name="xslTimeZone">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$targetTimeZone = 'CET'">PT2H</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>Not_Supported</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:variable name="tz-timestamp"
                select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($utc-timestamp, xs:dayTimeDuration($xslTimeZone))"/>
            <date UTC_timestamp="{$utc-timestamp}">
                <cet CET_timestamp="{$tz-timestamp}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="format-dateTime($tz-timestamp, '[M,2]/[D,2]/[Y,4] [h]:[m]:[s] [P]', 'de', (), 'de')"
                    />
                </cet>
            </date>
        </xs:testDate>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Takes e.g. this input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InputDateTime>
    <TargetTimeZone>CET</TargetTimeZone>
    <UTCDateTime>2019-11-15T09:15:00Z</UTCDateTime>
</InputDateTime>
```

And produces an proper output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:testDate xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <date UTC_timestamp="2019-11-15T09:15:00Z">
      <cet CET_timestamp="2019-11-15T11:15:00+02:00">11/15/2019 11:15:00 a.m.</cet>
   </date>
</xs:testDate>
```

Can anybody help me how to convert from any Java time zone like 'CET' to xslt duration like 'PT2H' without having all this manually maintained?

Thanks & Regards Marco

Comment: Isn't CET UTC+01:00?

Comment: CET  UTC+01:00
CEST UTC+02:00

But from my knowledge java only knows CET. But CET could be also DST --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones if you see the number of TZs I just don't want to use a static mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

There are REST APIs like http://worldtimeapi.org/ which allow you to request information about timezones so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="tz-api" as="xs:string">http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/</xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="InputDateTime">
      <date UTC_timestamp="{UTCDateTime}">
          <xsl:variable name="tz-map" select="json-doc($tz-api || TargetTimeZone)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="tz-dateTime" select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime(UTCDateTime), timezone-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime($tz-map?datetime)))"/>
          <local_date timestamp="{$tz-dateTime}">{format-dateTime($tz-dateTime, '[M,2]/[D,2]/[Y,4] [h]:[m]:[s] [P]', 'de', (), 'de')}</local_date>
      </date>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9G outputs

```
<date UTC_timestamp="2019-11-15T09:15:00Z">
   <local_date timestamp="2019-11-15T11:15:00+02:00">[Language: en]11/15/2019 11:15:00 a.m.</local_date>
</date>
```

I haven't checked any details about errors returned if the timezone abbreviation is not found by the REST API but I am sure XSLT 3 could handle it with `xsl:try`/`xsl:catch` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, found also a solution to include java coding like this:            <xsl:value-of select="zonedDateTime:ofInstant(instant:parse($utc-timestamp), zoneId:of($targetTimeZone))"
                    xmlns:instant="java:java.time.Instant" xmlns:zoneId="java:java.time.ZoneId"
                    xmlns:zonedDateTime="java:java.time.ZonedDateTime"
                    xmlns:dateTimeFormatter="java:java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter"/>

will try if I find a smooth solution for that.